# Change caption of button to field in a table using Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make the caption of a button the content of a field from a table.

Everything I am finding online in forums and MS websites only shows using a macro with the `OnClick`. I need it to display without every clicking. It also needs to dynamically change every time the field from the table changes.

How can I achieve this? Again, I don't want an event such as `OnClick`, I want it to simply read as the field from the table reads.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the Form's `OnCurrent` event to set the buttons caption.

**On Current:**

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Nz(Me.FieldName, "") <> "" Then
        Me.btnTest.Caption = Me.FieldName
    Else
        'Handle blank record here
    End If
End Sub
```

This will make it so ever time the selected record changes the button will update.  Also just add the code into the specific field's `AfterUpdate` event so it changes then as well.

**After Update:**

```
Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(Me.FieldName, "") <> "" Then
        Me.btnTest.Caption = Me.FieldName
    Else
        'Handle blank record here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, that's close. I'm actually using a combo box and want the selection from that box to be the caption for the button. Sorry I wasn't very clear with my original post. The combo box is tied to the table. Thanks.